# Does using -parallel or (and) -vec will make our program run faster?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, intel

I'm using Linux & Intel compiler (C/C++).

My code does not use CilkPlus or OpenMp.
I read the following article :
[Auto-Parallelization Overview](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-C109A0DE-0CCF-4FE4-8A03-05DBA5D8BD77.htm)

And I'm confused:

1. If I'm not using OpenMp (or CilkPlus) and compile my program with
   "-parallel" (auto-parallelizer) and "-vec" (Auto-vectorization), will the  program run faster (because the compiler break serial code to parallel code ?)
2. if so (it will run faster), why it is not the default option ? (why not to use those flags ) ?

Thanks

Comment: Best way to find out is to just try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel uses such techniques like loop unwinding, task decomposition & etc to parallel your code. These techniques probably make your program run faster but some problem may be occurred when the program faces [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), tasks done by priority and .... So it can not be used as default.

Comment: 1. race conditions and deadlock may occur if I'm writing parallel code by my self. so what is the different ? (or it is the same... and just to be aware ?)

Comment: 2. if my application is safe (without race condition, Can I enable those to flags without worry ?

Comment: 1. You can not predict race condition and deadlock in serial code that parallel. You must review your code and algorithms that used in to parallel it.

Comment: 2. Definitely yes, for example consider matrix multiplication's loop unwinding or task decomposition.

Comment: `race conditions and deadlock may occur if I'm writing parallel code by my self. ` Only if you write bad code...